# Unable to intersect with search cursor on ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, intersect

I would like to loop through the shapes in the attribute table and create a new intersection point feature class for each row in the table. But every time I do this, I keep on getting the same error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\analysis.py", line 289, in Intersect
raise e
ValueError: DescribeGeometry: Unexpected error
```

This is the portion of the code I am working on, where tribufline and water_feature are line feature class. I t would be really helpful is someone is able to point me in the right direction because I have no idea what is causing this error

```
for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tribufline, ["SHAPE@", "OID@"]):
   line = row[0]
   culint = "triculint{0}".format(row[1])
   arcpy.Intersect_analysis([line, water_feature], culint, "ALL", "","POINT")
```

Comment: Why go through each row if you can do them all in one go with a tool?

Answer (score 4):

You mention that water_feature is a Feature Class, but in the arcpy.Intersect_analysis you are using a geometry (line) with a feature class (water_feature).  I'm not sure which is right, but I would think they should both be geometries or they should both be feature classes.

Comment: I think you are right that there may be a mismatch trying to do a line-on-line overlay between something that is just a geometry and something that has attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should start by adding a `print` statement to see which particular OID this is erroring on.

However, there are a few other things that I think you could do to improve your code snippet for testing:

```
import arcpy
tribufline = ???
water_feature = ???
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(tribufline, ["SHAPE@", "OID@"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print "Processing OID: {0}".format(row[1])
        line = row[0]
        culint = "triculint{0}".format(row[1])
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis([line, water_feature], culint, "ALL", "","POINT")
```

The output from the code snippet above should be more informative than what you have posted.